# How to use fixed width font in python indicator in Unity's top panel?

Tags: unity, python, gtk

I have a python script of network bandwidth indicator that I have downloaded from here : https://launchpad.net/nettraffic

I would like to make the indicator use a fixed font so that the indicator's width in Unity's top panel won't change.

How can I use a fixed-width font in there ?

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably want to set the `label-guide` property to the maximum width.

According to the [docs](http://developer.ubuntu.com/api/ubuntu-12.04/python/AppIndicator3-0.1.html):

> An optional string to provide guidance to the panel on how big the
>   #AppIndicator:label string could get. If this is set correctly then the panel should never 'jiggle' as the string adjusts through out the
>   range of options. For instance, if you were providing a percentage
>   like "54% thrust" in #AppIndicator:label you'd want to set this string
>   to "100% thrust" to ensure space when Scotty can get you enough power.

Comment: I am trying to do: `self.guide = "999.99 MiB/s↓ 999.99 MiB/s↑"; self.ind.set_property('label-guide', self.guide)` but this does not work.

Comment: @Patryk: you're right. I just did some testing, and it doesn't work for me either. That means the docs are wrong or a bug in the appindicator. Either way, a bugreport should be in place.

Comment: Yes, you're right. How can I report the bug since I have tried to find bug report functionality here [https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/quantal/amd64/python-gtop/2.32.0+dfsg-1](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/quantal/amd64/python-gtop/2.32.0+dfsg-1) but there is nothing there.

Comment: You should report it to `libappindicator`, not `gtop`. https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libappindicator